# How to Call a Function with JQuery Only When Screen Resizes to a Specific Width?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, media-queries

How can I get this function below to be called only when the screen is resized to a specific width, like media queries? (600px max-width particularly, in this demo.)

Here is what I've developed so far, but I must not be doing something right...

```js
$(function() {
  if ($(window).screen.width <= 600) {
    $(".content").each(function(t) {
      len = $(this).text().length, len > 5 && $(this).text($(this).text().substr(0, 5) + "...")
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="content">CONDENSE THIS TEXT</span>
```

Comment: You're missing a `)` after `window`

Comment: Ok, thanks. I just added that to my snippet. Still doesn't seem to be working though. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Also remove the redundant `);` after the first `});`

Comment: So, I applied these edits, but still no luck to get it working. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution:

```js
function checkWidth() {
  if ($(window).width() < 600) {
    $('#content').addClass('fulltxt');
    $("#content").each(function(i) {
      len = $(this).text().length;
      if (len > 5) {
        $(this).text($(this).text().substr(0, 5) + '...');
      }
    })
  } else {
    $('#content').removeClass('fulltxt');
    $("#content").each(function(i) {
      $(this).text($(this).data('originaltxt'));
    });
  }
}
$("#content").each(function() {
  $(this).data({
    originaltxt: $(this).text()
  });
});
$(window).resize(checkWidth);
```

```css
#content {
  border: 2px solid green;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
}

#content.fulltxt {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="content">CONDENSE THIS TEXT</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `window.onresize`, which will catch resize events:

```
$(function() {
  window.onresize = function(event) {
    if (window.screen.width <= 600) {
      $(".content").each(function(t) {
        var len = $(this).text().length;
        if (len > 5) $(this).text($(this).text().slice(0, 5) + "...")
      });
    }
  }
});

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="content">CONDENSE THIS TEXT</span>
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. However, it did not seem to affect the content. I was pointed by another user to rephrase my original question, for further clarification, so the solution I am looking for has to do with the function being called when the screen is resized to a max-width of 600px.

Comment: The function will fire anytime the window is resized. I tried it in the console and it ran as expected...

Comment: Ok. I've tried your exact code, but I still can't see the function applied when the screen is at a max-width of 600px. See here: https://jsfiddle.net/bpyLjxom/

Comment: Figured it out with a different approach. Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery does not have a `screen` property, use `window.screen`. Note that using comma operator defines `len` as the result of the expression following `,`

```js
$(function() {
  if (window.screen.width <= 600) {
    $(".content").each(function(t) {
      var len = $(this).text().length;
      if (len > 5) $(this).text($(this).text().slice(0, 5) + "...")
    });
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="content">CONDENSE THIS TEXT</span>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but your snippet doesn't seem to work, when resized to 600px width... Does it work for you?

Comment: The original question does not mention "resized", see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. The code at OP uses an `if` condition exactly once. Use `resize` event to dispatch a function when the viewport changes dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

Just use jQuery `width()`:

```js
$(function() {
  if ($(window).width() <= 1000) {
    $(".content").each(function(t) {
      len = $(this).text().length, len > 5 && $(this).text($(this).text().substr(0, 5) + "...")
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="content">CONDENSE THIS TEXT</span>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it still isn't working. Have you tried the snippet in your answer?

Comment: Yes, it works - but the screen is more than 600px wide.  If you run it on a small screen, or in the sandbox, it condenses the text.  For demonstration, I've updated the width to 1000px.